# Trouble running a macro which selects every second column in a range and inputs the result in a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that selects every second column and inputs the addresses in to an excel defined function:

```
Dim calcrange As Range
Dim c As Long
Set calcrange = Range("InvestmentOutlay")
For c = 3 To Range("C57").End(xlToRight).Column Step 2
    Set calcrange = Union(calcrange, Cells(57, c))
Next
Range("IRR").Formula = "=IRR((" & calcrange.Address & "))"
```

This code works, however, when I try to run this code:

```
Dim npvRange As Range
Dim n As Long
Set npvRange = Range("C57")
For n = 3 To Range("C57").End(xlToRight).Column Step 2
    Set npvRange = Union(Range("C57"), Cells(57, n))
Next
Range("NPV").Formula = "=NPV((EconGrowth1," & npvRange.Address & "))"
```

I get an "Application defined or object defined error". The debug highlights the last line of code. I'm still pretty new with VBA, and am unsure what is causing this error, and how to fix it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks,

Comment: What is `EconGrowth1`? (Btw your npvRange doesn't look right.)

Comment: EconGrowth1 is a named range that is a percent. The Net Present Value in excel (NPV) requires it as the first argument in the function. Can you elaborate about what doesn't look right about it? I'm honestly stumped...

Comment: I don't know if it would cause an error, but `npvRange` will only be set to the last value in the loop because you are overwriting the previous setting of n (whereas in the calcrange loop you are incorporating the previous range in the union). In other words, I guess you should have `Set npvRange = Union(npvrange, Cells(57, n))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets you are placing around both the `EconGrowth1` and `npvRange` values is making them into one parameter, but `EconGrowth1` should be the first parameter, and the other cells should be the second parameter.

So you need to move your brackets:

```
Range("NPV").Formula = "=NPV(EconGrowth1,(" & npvRange.Address & "))"
```

---

And, as SJR mentioned in a comment, your `Union` should be changed to:

```
Set npvRange = Union(npvRange, Cells(57, n))
```

---

And, as you have already initialised `npvRange` to be `C57`, you can start the loop at column 5.

The final code could look like:

```
Dim npvRange As Range
Dim n As Long
Set npvRange = Range("C57")
For n = 5 To Range("C57").End(xlToRight).Column Step 2
    Set npvRange = Union(npvRange, Cells(57, n))
Next
Range("NPV").Formula = "=NPV(EconGrowth1,(" & npvRange.Address & "))"
```

---

SJR has just pointed out in a comment that the `NPV` formula doesn't even need brackets because, unlike the `IRR` formula which only takes one parameter for `values`, the `NPV` formula has parameters of `rate, value1, [value2], ...`.

So that means the `Formula` line can be just:

```
Range("NPV").Formula = "=NPV(EconGrowth1," & npvRange.Address & ")"
```

Comment: I've never used NPV but I think you might be able to dispense with the brackets altogether. I didn't think they would cause an error though so what do I know...

Comment: @SJR You're probably right, it seems that the parameters can be `(rate, value1, [value2], [value3], ...)`.  (I originally added them into the IRR formula because it just has `(values, guess)`, and therefore needed the brackets to group the cells being used for `values`.)

Comment: I don't see why the double brackets cause an error. `=sum((a1:a2))` is fine.

Comment: @ SJR @YowE3K Thank you both so much. That did it. Yow, you heped me out the other day as well, thanks again. I hate to sound completely ignorant, but I seem to be up against a steep learning curve; VBA is really the first "programming" I have ever tried. Are there any books or resources you'd recommend to develop a more technical proficiency on programming? Thanks

Comment: @SJR - the extra brackets won't be an issue, but the IRR formula **without** the double brackets did cause an issue (i.e. `=IRR(InvestmentOutlay,$C$57,$E$57,$G$57)` didn't work because it had to be `=IRR((InvestmentOutlay,$C$57,$E$57,$G$57))`.

Comment: @jules325 - I learned to program from a book called "Computer Programming Made Simple", which gave a simple guide to COBOL and FORTRAN (the only real languages available back then).  Everything else has been learned by 40+ years of experience.  And I'm still learning more every day by reading (and attempting to answer) SO questions.

Comment: YowE3K - thanks for clarifying. @jules325 - I haven't read it, but John Walkenbach's book is supposed to be good. There is so much online though. Hang around here and forums like it as you are - the best experience is to solve an actual problem as you have.